# What does it mean to keep on getting kicked out of Beanstalk?

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, beanstalkd, forge

## Background

We used [Laravel Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189802/how-to-monitor-redis-as-a-queue-engine-using-cli-similar-to-beanstalkd) on top of [beanstalkd](https://forge.laravel.com/) on two EC2 instances (behind a load balancer). Our AWS EC2 instances are auto-provisioned using [forge](https://forge.laravel.com/), including the supervisor that makes sure that beanstalk is always running.

With beanstalkd, I used beanstalk utilities to monitor the health of the queue; for example, if the queue was getting clogged, I could easily see that by running a command like this:

```
./beanstalk-queue-stats.rb localhost:11300
```

which would return something like this

```
2018-01-10 11:08:38 +0000
default
 - cmd-delete = 32678 (+32678)
 - cmd-pause-tube = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-buried = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-delayed = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-ready = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-reserved = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-urgent = 0 (0)
 - current-using = 5 (+5)
 - current-waiting = 0 (0)
 - current-watching = 2 (+2)
 - pause = 0 (0)
 - pause-time-left = 0 (0)
 - total-jobs = 32678 (+32678)
high
 - cmd-delete = 116005 (+116005)
 - cmd-pause-tube = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-buried = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-delayed = 9 (+9)
 - current-jobs-ready = 1117 (+1117)
 - current-jobs-reserved = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-urgent = 0 (0)
 - current-using = 0 (0)
 - current-waiting = 0 (0)
 - current-watching = 1 (+1)
 - pause = 0 (0)
 - pause-time-left = 0 (0)
 - total-jobs = 117131 (+117131)
low
 - cmd-delete = 0 (0)
 - cmd-pause-tube = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-buried = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-delayed = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-ready = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-reserved = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-urgent = 0 (0)
 - current-using = 0 (0)
 - current-waiting = 0 (0)
 - current-watching = 1 (+1)
 - pause = 0 (0)
 - pause-time-left = 0 (0)
 - total-jobs = 0 (0)
marketing
 - cmd-delete = 0 (0)
 - cmd-pause-tube = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-buried = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-delayed = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-ready = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-reserved = 0 (0)
 - current-jobs-urgent = 0 (0)
 - current-using = 0 (0)
 - current-waiting = 0 (0)
 - current-watching = 1 (+1)
 - pause = 0 (0)
 - pause-time-left = 0 (0)
 - total-jobs = 0 (0)
------------------
```

etc. (see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189802/how-to-monitor-redis-as-a-queue-engine-using-cli-similar-to-beanstalkd))

The problem is that I keep on getting kicked out of Beanstalk with this error

```
/home/forge/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/beanstalk-client-1.1.1/lib/beanstalk-client/connection.rb:212:in `check_resp': NOT_FOUND (Beanstalk::NotFoundError)
    from /home/forge/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/beanstalk-client-1.1.1/lib/beanstalk-client/connection.rb:231:in `read_yaml'
    from /home/forge/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/beanstalk-client-1.1.1/lib/beanstalk-client/connection.rb:195:in `interact'
    from /home/forge/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/beanstalk-client-1.1.1/lib/beanstalk-client/connection.rb:173:in `stats_tube'
    from ./beanstalk-queue-stats.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from ./beanstalk-queue-stats.rb:19:in `each'
    from ./beanstalk-queue-stats.rb:19:in `block in <main>'
    from ./beanstalk-queue-stats.rb:17:in `loop'
    from ./beanstalk-queue-stats.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

This happens on both instances. I checked the workers on Forge, and they seem to be fine:

```
worker-157645:worker-157645_00   RUNNING   pid 10110, uptime 0:25:47
worker-157646:worker-157646_00   RUNNING   pid 10236, uptime 0:25:44
worker-157647:worker-157647_00   RUNNING   pid 10336, uptime 0:25:42
worker-157648:worker-157648_00   RUNNING   pid 10472, uptime 0:25:36
```

and more importantly, the pid is not changing (I would assume the pids would change every time Beanstalk crashes.. but it seems it's not)

Needless to say, this is messing up our system as the jobs that are supposed to be processed in the queue are sometimes working, sometimes not working, sometimes take a while to work.

Any ideas?

## Update

If I grep the processes running Beanstalk, I get all of these:

```
forge     1596  0.1  0.2  65648 10632 pts/1    Sl+  09:11   0:00 ruby ./beanstalk-queue-stats.rb localhost:11300
forge     1956  0.0  0.0   4512   700 ?        S    09:12   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='default' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=6 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge     1957  2.0  1.2 384800 49532 ?        S    09:12   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=default --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=6 --tries=3 --env=production
forge     1996  0.0  0.0   4512   788 ?        S    09:12   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='low' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=9 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge     1997  3.5  1.2 384800 49616 ?        S    09:12   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=low --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=9 --tries=3 --env=production
forge     2036  0.0  0.0   4512   744 ?        S    09:12   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='high' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=2 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge     2037  5.5  1.2 384800 49360 ?        S    09:12   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=high --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=2 --tries=3 --env=production
forge     2041  0.0  0.0   4512   804 ?        S    09:12   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='marketing' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge     2042 12.0  1.2 384800 49368 ?        S    09:12   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=marketing --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --env=production
forge     2059  0.0  0.0  12924  1036 pts/3    S+   09:12   0:00 grep --color=auto beanstalk
forge    10110  0.1  1.1 374208 46108 ?        S    08:18   0:04 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=2 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=high
forge    10236  0.0  1.1 374208 46568 ?        S    08:19   0:02 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=6 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=default
forge    10336  0.0  1.1 374208 46588 ?        S    08:19   0:01 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=9 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=low
forge    10472  0.0  1.1 374204 46572 ?        S    08:19   0:02 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=3 --quiet --timeout=60 --tries=3 --queue=marketing
beansta+ 17275  0.0  0.1  25124  4600 ?        Ss    2017  21:49 /usr/bin/beanstalkd -l 0.0.0.0 -p 11300
```

Something doesn't look right, there seems to be so many.

Comment: It looks like a good chuck of this question [is copy-pasted from your prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189802/how-to-monitor-redis-as-a-queue-engine-using-cli-similar-to-beanstalkd). I accept it may not be a duplicate, but we're very wary of copy-pasta on Stack Overflow. If you must post a lot of duplicate material, it may be worth adding a note in the body (or in subsequent posts, link to the first one rather than duplicating the material).

Comment: It looks like you have so much all-lower-case in your posts, I wonder if this is done deliberately for stylistic reasons. If so, please don't do that! We expect 14K users to stick to technical/reference quality writing as much as they are able to, to aid readability. Thanks if you can repair!

Comment: (Your second para seems to have a broken link?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor Redis as a queue engine using cli similar to beanstalkd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189802/how-to-monitor-redis-as-a-queue-engine-using-cli-similar-to-beanstalkd)